# Get the number of cart items in logout page

Tags: php, magento, logout, cart

How can I get the number of cart items in logout page, I try to use the following code, it works in cart.phtml but not in logout.phtml

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
echo 'cart items count: ' . $cart;
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
echo 'cart items count: ' . $cart;
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
echo 'cart items count: ' . $cart;
```

I suppose since it is already logged out it doesn't get access any more, should I try to get that information using cookies?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i use this :

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote()->getItemsCount()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I use

```
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
```

in my `mini.login.phtml` which I put in the footer of my pages and the good news is it does get the item count in the cart. The bad news is, it does not update immediately after I add a product, so I need to refresh the cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
```

This is stated and points to your getItemsCount();

Why does this need two lines to just say the third line of code? Not trying to be mean just asking.

What im saying is: Why not use this.

```
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
echo 'cart items count: ' . $cart;
```

Once instead of stating the same thing twice with less information.

Comment: I just display 3 different ways that I was trying to get items but all of them return zero, even when exist items in cart.

I suppose that I need access to the database or cookies to check if exist item, because at that page logout.phtml i'm already logout as user and not access any more to that user.

Comment: You would need access otherwise it appears that there isn't any item in the cart.